# Moving Wordpress from one folder to another

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to move my Wordpress (v4.3.1) site from the folder `example.com/articles` to `example.com/blog` without success. First, I changed `siteurl` and `home` fields in the `wp_options` table, then I renamed the `articles` folder into `blog` and visited `example.com/blog/wp-login.php`. The login page displays unstyled because a lot of paths refer to `/articles//blog/` (yes with a double slash). Logging in also fails because the page is submitted to `articles//blog/wp-login.php`.

Other things I've tried without success:

1. Changed `siteurl` and `home` through Wordpress's Settings > General (instead of making this change straight into the database)
2. Cleared my cookies
3. Added to `wp-config.php` `define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/blog')` and `define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/blog')`
4. Deleted everything from `.htaccess` and ran `/wp-admin/index.php` (to regenerate `.htaccess`)
5. Changed the contents of `.htaccess'` to the code below:

Code in .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any other things I can try?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing right now after all the listed changes above ? or do you have URL ?

Comment: @Ajith The problem has been resolved, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! The problem was the value of the field `wordpress-https_ssl_host` in the `wp_options` table. I've changed it from `https://www.example.com/article/` to `https://www.example.com/blog/`. I assume this value has been set by the WordPress HTTPS (SSL) plugin.